# initializing array of structure with array elements in it

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    typedef struct s
    {
        int a;
        int b[5];
        char c[2];
    }st;

    st vs[1];

    vs[0] = {1,{1,2,3,4,5},{'c','d'}};

    printf("%d:a\n",vs[1].a);
    printf("%d:b[0]\t %d:b[4]\n",vs[0].b[0],vs[0].b[4]);
    printf("%c:c[0]\t %c:c[1]\n",vs[0].c[0],vs[0].c[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

why does this doesn't work?

on

```
gcc -o main *.c
```

I get this error

> main.c: In function 'main':
>       main.c:15:12: error: expected expression before '{' token
>            vs[0] ={1,{1,2,3,4,5},{'c','d'}};

But if I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    typedef struct s
    {
        int a;
        int b[5];
        char c[2];
    }st;

    st vs[] = {
                {1,{1,2,3,4,5},{'c','d'}}
              };

    printf("%d:a\n",vs[0].a);
    printf("%d:b[0]\t %d:b[4]\n",vs[0].b[0],vs[0].b[4]);
    printf("%c:c[0]\t %c:c[1]\n",vs[0].c[0],vs[0].c[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

it works. What is the logic in this.

How can I make it work using st vs[1] method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Initialization* is when you declare a variable and provide initial values for it as part of the declaration. For example this is legal:

```
st vs[1] = { {1,{1,2,3,4,5},{'c','d'}} };
```

Your code is actually attempting *assignment*.  Assignment is when an existing variable has a value assigned to it.  The reason your code doesn't work is that `{1,{1,2,3,4,5},{'c','d'}}` isn't a value.

In a statement (not a declaration), each expression must be readable by the compiler on its own merit, and a more complicated statement is made up of various expressions joined by operators.  So the compiler doesn't know what to do with `{1,{1,2,3,4,5},{'c','d'}}`  - at this stage it has no idea that that is supposed to be a `st`.

Since C99 there is a new language construct you can use here, called *compound literal*:

```
vs[0] = (const st){1,{1,2,3,4,5},{'c','d'}};
```

Note that this is not a cast operator being applied to some sort of braced expression;  it is a single syntactic construct `(Typename){ initializers }` .

My use of `const` is a micro-optimization, it may help the compiler store the literal in a read-only block of the executable and allow constant folding.

Answer (score 8):

You can only do *braced initialization* when you declare a variable. So,

```
st vs[] = {
            {1,{1,2,3,4,5},{'c','d'}}
          };
```

is allowed. But

```
vs[0] = {1,{1,2,3,4,5},{'c','d'}};
```

is not. Because this is not a initialization but assignment.

However, you can use `C99`'s compound literal, see [C11, 6.5.2.5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5):

```
vs[0] = (struct s){1,{1,2,3,4,5},{'c','d'}};
```